# Firebase auth in React Native is hanging on the first attempt

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm experiencing a weird issue when trying to authenticate against Firebase in React Native. When clicking the button to login, nothing happens until I've clicked it again. It's getting stuck somewhere but I don't know why. I've managed to do this successfully in the past so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. It might be package versions, but then surely it shouldn't authenticate at all if that was the issue?

I'm currently just using a barebones expo RN project with two files, App.js and firebase.js.

I tried using the same firebase config in a React web project and it worked just fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import fireBase from './firebase';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this);
  }

  signIn = () => {
    fireBase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword('email@email.com', 'password')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.login} onPress={() => this.signIn()}>
          <Text>login test</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightyellow',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20
  },
  login: {
    width: '50%',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    padding: 8,
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});

export default App;
```

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: ''
};

const fireBase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default fireBase;
```

(my firebase.js file has config values, I'm just not posting them here)

It should give me the res or error on the first attempt but it only happens after clicking the button a second time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by not using Expo CLI, but React Native CLI to generate a project instead and using react-native-firebase package. It's a bit of a pain to set up initially but once done, it works fine.